# What does mean @GeneratedValue, @Basic(optional=false) in JPA?

Tags: jpa

I'm creating a Below Java class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "relationshiplist")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({

    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM employeeTable r")})

public class GetEmployee implements Serializable{

 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "pkey")
    private Integer pkey;
    @Size(max = 12)

 private String category;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "relationshipListpkey", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<categoryList> categoryList;

}
```

1.What is the use of

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

2.What is the use of `@Basic(optional = false)`

3.what is the use of `@OneToMany(cascade=cascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="employeelistPkey")`

Can anyone explain.

Comment: What did the JPA documentation say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things you have asked is widely available in numerous docs at Internet. You can easily scheme through those by yourself after searching on Yahoo/Google. However, I am giving you few reference links, If you read the docs with a care, I believe you'll find the answers yourself.

http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/annotations/field

http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/annotations/relationship

http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/annotations/value